# ¿Cómo diferencio dos campos de una base de datos que se llaman igual para mostrarlos en una consulta mediante php?

Tags: php, sql

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema, necesito mostrar una consulta que me muestre los socios que no han pagado un determinado curso, pero tengo dos campos que se llaman nombre, cursillos.nombre y socios.nombre, mi problema es que cuando la ejecuto me muestra en los dos campos socios.nombre

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");



$sql="SELECT cursillos.codcurso, cursillos.nombre, socios.nombre from 
cursillos inner join socios on cursillos.codcurso=socios.codcurso order 
by cursillos.nombre";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "<h2><center>SOCIOS APUNTADOS</center></h2>
<table border='1' style='margin: 0 auto;'>
<thead>
        <tr>
        <th>CÓDIGO CURSO</th>
        <th>NOMBRE CURSO</th>
        <th>NOMBRE SOCIO</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

       echo'
    <tr>
        <td><center>'.$row["codcurso"].'</center></td>
        <td><center>'.$row["nombre"].'</center></td>
        <td><center>'.$row["nombre"].'</center></td></tr>';


}
} else {
    echo "0 resultados";
}
echo "</table></div>";
echo '<a href="consultaCursos.php">Volver al listado</a>';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

En el select utiliza `as` para darle un nuevo nombre:

```
SELECT cursillos.codcurso, cursillos.nombre as cNombre, socios.nombre as sNombre from 
cursillos inner join socios on cursillos.codcurso=socios.codcurso order 
by cursillos.nombre
```

Y luego accede al array con el mismo nombre utilizado:

```
<td><center>'.$row["codcurso"].'</center></td>
<td><center>'.$row["cNombre"].'</center></td>
<td><center>'.$row["sNombre "].'</center></td></tr>';
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Comment: nada perdona, había sido un error mío me ha funcionado perfecto, Gracias!

Comment: Perfecto jaja, penasba que igual te estaba dando problemas el order by :D